# TensorFlow bidirectional LSTM encoding of word embeddings

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a word embedding matrix containing a vector for each word. I am trying to use TensorFlow to get the bidirectional LSTM encoding of each word given the embedding vectors. Unfortunately, I get the following error message:

> ValueError: Shapes (1, 125) and () must have the same rank
>   Exception TypeError: TypeError("'NoneType' object is not callable",) in  ignored

Here is the code I used:

```
     # Declare max number of words in a sentence
    self.max_len = 100
    # Declare number of dimensions for word embedding vectors
    self.wdims = 100

     # Indices of words in the sentence
    self.wrd_holder = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [self.max_len])
    # Embedding Matrix
    wrd_lookup = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([len(vocab)+3, self.wdims], stddev=1.0 / np.sqrt(self.wdims)))

     # Declare forward and backward cells
    forward  = rnn_cell.LSTMCell(125, (self.wdims))
    backward = rnn_cell.LSTMCell(125, (self.wdims))

     # Perform lookup
    wrd_embd = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(wrd_lookup, self.wrd_holder)
    embd = tf.split(0, self.max_len, wrd_embd)

     # run bidirectional LSTM
    boutput = rnn.bidirectional_rnn(forward, backward, embd, dtype=tf.float32, sequence_length=self.max_len)
```

Answer (score 2):

the sequence length passed to rnn must be a vector of length batch size.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11959085)

Comment: To clarify, you use max_len as sequence_length.  This is a scalar. Either don't pass it, or pass [max_len] * batch_size, which is the expected vector.